# How to Search for an array value in MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb

I have my collection like below

```
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(366),
    "_class" : "com.cts.adpart.domain.DBData",
    "file" : "xyz",
    "sample" : [
                   "a",
                   "b",
                   "c"
             ]
}
```

I want to search sample array based on list values 
Suppose now 
1. my List is having values "a","c" then i want above document to be returned but,
2. if my list contains "a","d" It should not return above document.

I have tried below code but it is returning me the document even if one match is found.

```
List<String> sampleList = new ArrayList<String>();
sampleList.add("a");
sampleList.add("d");

query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("sample").in(sampleList));
```

How to change the query so that it returns document only if all values in `list` matches the field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use the $all operator

```
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("sample").all(sampleList));
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to have exact match, you should query just by the elements in the array. For eg:

```
{"sample":['a','b','c']}
```

Refer [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/query-documents/#exact-match-on-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [all](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/Criteria.html#all-java.util.Collection-) method of class [Criteria](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/Criteria.html). As this [document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) says:

> The `$all` operator selects the documents where the value of a field is an array that contains all the specified elements.

So, you should modify your statement as follows.

```
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("sample").all(sampleList));
```